# Why is dereference of past-the-end iterator of std::basic_string still UB after C++11?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17, undefined-behavior, stdstring

As we all knows, C++11 adds a null terminator to `std::basic_string` (which doesn't count into most member functions). But when I read [cpp ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/end), I found dereference of `end()` an UB (this paragraph is almost the same to [the one for std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end)). Why does this happen?
Or is this an error of cpp ref (please provide the doc for this for verification)?

I tried on GNU C++ but unfortunately __gnu_debug seems not to contain checker for `std::string` iterator. Neither does sanitizer of Clang++.

Comment: Why is it worth special casing `std::string::end()` to be okay when other calls to `end` wouldn't be?

Comment: Because it must always be a null character. That means it is different from the rest of characters who can aquire arbitrary values. If you modify the end character through dereferencing the iterator, the string will end up in undefined state.

Answer (score 7):

Correct; the `end()` iterator cannot be indirected, even though `[data(), data() + size()]` is a closed range.

The only major compiler that I know to enforce this in debug mode is Microsoft Visual Studio:

```cpp
#include <string>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return *std::string(argv[argc - 1]).end();
}
```

The above program compiled as `cl.exe a.cpp /EHsc /Zi /MDd /std:c++20 /D_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=2` gives the following debug assertion:

> Expression: cannot dereference string iterator because it is out of range (e.g. an end iterator)

(libstdc++ does not perform iterator debugging for `std::string` [by design](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode_design.html), to allow ABI compatibility between debug and release mode; libc++ [claims](https://releases.llvm.org/12.0.0/projects/libcxx/docs/DesignDocs/DebugMode.html#iterator-debugging-checks) to perform iterator debugging for `std::string` but [does not appear](https://clang.godbolt.org/z/qdhdeonfG) to catch this error.)

The reason for this seeming inconsistency in the standard is that the null terminator is provided as a convenience for C-style APIs that expect null-terminated strings; but these are accessing the string via a raw character pointer, not an iterator. So making the past-the-end iterator dereferenceable would do nothing to help such code and could hide bugs in the use of C++-style iterators.

Comment: Good to know that MSVC can capture this dereference. Actually, it seems turning on debug building (`/MTd` or `/MDd`) is enough to trigger the debug assertion.

Comment: In my test clang + libc++ can capture the problem. Tested with llvm-14 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The Godbolt clang compiler probably has not enabled the debug mode support.